# php ajax error ...not showing the data

Tags: php, ajax

///this is the form part .where i am trying get data from database and show it in "txt" part.the script part is in same file and getService.php is in the same directory as this file.why showing nothing when i select something.

```
<form>
<select name="parent">
<option selected="users" onchange="showService(this.value)">Select a Service:</option>
<?php
$res=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM service");
while($row=$res->fetch_array())
{
  ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
</br>

</form>



<div id="txt"><b>Service info will be show here...</b></div>


    </center>

    </div>
```

//script part. in same file.

```
<script>
function showService(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getService.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
```

//getService.php

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once'db_connect.php';


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM service WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>

<th>id</th>
<th>Service name</th>
<th>Detail</th>

</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['detail'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your getService.php should not return a whole new HTML page to insert inside another one, this is not really valid markup. Instead return only the `<table>` part which is actually required to go within the specific part of the page

Comment: in the meantime you should check your browser's console and network tabs in the Developer Tools to see if any HTTP errors occurred, and to check if you correctly passed the parameter to the server, and what (if any) response occurred. Also your SQL is very vulnerable to injection attacks - you should use parameterised queries, you can google this easily.

Comment: lastly is "id" meant to be an integer? Because in your query you send it in quotes to mySQL like a string, so it won't match it to an integer in the table. Again if you used proper parameterised queries this kind of problem will just disappear.

Comment: sorry one more thing `document.getElementById("txtHint")` You don't have any element with this ID in your HTML. Try `document.getElementById("txt")` instead

Comment: @ADyson thank for txt part but not showing anything. console is showing GET http://localhost/project/admin/style.css

Comment: anything in the network tab after you make a selection? You should see another GET to getService.php and some sort of response and/or error. Unless of course `str == ""` is true? You can maybe put in an `alert` or `console.log` at the start of your function to test this

Comment: oh hang on, just realised `onchange="showService(this.value)"` should be an attribute of the `<select>` not the `<option>`. So it probably isn't firing the event at all.

Comment: @ADyson the last one is right .....in select not in option ...many thanks

Comment: I will add the various bits as an answer to bring it all together

Comment: If you would consider upvoting / marking as answer I would be grateful, and it will be helpful for future readers too - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. In order of direct relevance to your question:

1) `onchange="showService(this.value)"` should be an attribute of the `<select>` not the first `<option>`. So it isn't firing the change event at all, meaning your ajax call never runs.

2) `document.getElementById("txtHint")` is wrong (in two places) - you don't have any element with this ID in your HTML. `document.getElementById("txt")` should work.

3) Your getService.php should not return a whole new HTML page (with DocType, html, body tags etc) to insert inside a div in another page, this is not really valid markup. Instead return only the `<table>` part which is actually required to go within the specific part of the main page. If you need the CSS which is in getService.php, move it into your main page, or a separate CSS file which is included in the main page.

4) You process `q` as an int (using `intval()`) but then pass it to mySQL as if it is a string (by putting single quotes around it in the SQL statement). If the `id` field in your database is an integer, this will cause the values not to be considered equal to each other and so no results will be returned. If this is the case then you should remove the single quotes.

5) However, point 4 above is a symptom of another problem, in that you should not be adding variables into your query simply by joining PHP strings together. This leaves you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks where a malicious user could steal, corrupt or delete your data by inserting SQL into the variable itself. Instead you should use parameterised queries to guard against this, and also remove the potential for problems as described in point 4. http://bobby-tables.com/ is a good resource which explains both the dangers of injection attacks and contains resources explaining how to use parameterised queries and other techniques to guard against it, including examples using PHP. This is a good habit to get into now and will safeguard the data in your application.